# Exceptions raised as RuntimeException when using @Security

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.4

In my application I have an `ApplicationException` class that extends Exception. For many error cases I raise this `ApplicationException` with a predefined message. I also have an error handler class that extends `HttpErrorHandler`. There, in the `onServerError()` method I check if the exception raised is an `ApplciationException`. If so, I return the error message as a JSON string. Otherwise, I return a generic error message.

Everything worked as intended, until I added the `@Security` annotation to my controllers methods. Since then, all the exceptions are being uplifted to `java.lang.RuntimeException`.

As an example, here is what is thrown:

```
- with @Security annotation: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.mypackage.ApplicationException: Invalid value supplied for entered parameter 'sort'
- without @Security annotation: com.mypackage.ApplicationException: Invalid value supplied for entered parameter 'sort'
```

My Authenticator class (the one that extends `Security.Authenticator`) only has the `getUsername()` and `onUnauthorized()` method overridden.

Is there a way to preserve the `ApplicationException` while still using the `@Security`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty unfortunate (and bad practice) but the `@Security` annotation by default has a catch all exception handler as seen [here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/888c0f68d2233ae9098f7d533f73c395c20fc97f/framework/src/play/src/main/java/play/mvc/Security.java#L64).

Note: `Throwable` is the parent of both `Exception` and `RuntimeException`

The only option I think you have is to re-implement the `@Security` action wrapper with your own (`@MySecurity`?) and re-implement the `call` method specifically without the catch all handler and maybe put your own.

Hope that helps somewhat.

Comment: I see. I should have looked over the source of the Security class. Sadly, it seems that you are right and the only way would be to override the call() method in a derived class.